# Is there anyway to change the position and size of UIPopoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios

I want to use UIPopoverPresentationController. I have view controller which will be displayed in popover controller. However, I want to dismiss current popover and recreate and present again continuously.This implementation will cause the screen blinking. So If there is anyway to change the position and size of UIPopoverPresentationController ?